# User.IsInRole() not returning expected results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

In my MVC 5 project I implemented IUserStore<>, IUserRoleStore<>, IRoleStore<>, IUserPasswordStore<> to manage users and roles stored in my database. Now when I call:

```
if (User.IsInRole("roleName"))
```

inside my Razor View or Controller I get strange results. Inside my Seed(MyDbContext context) method I create three roles:

```
UserRoleStore us = new UserRoleStore(context);

foreach (var role in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RolesEnum)).Cast<RolesEnum>())
    us.CreateAsync(new Role(role.ToString()));
```

and two types of users - one with Admin role and other with Salesman role. In my layout page I have:

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if(User.IsInRole(Clinic.Enums.RolesEnum.Admin.ToString()))
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin", routeValues: new { area = "" }, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
    }
    if (User.IsInRole(Clinic.Enums.RolesEnum.Salesman.ToString()))
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Salesman", "Index", "Salesman", routeValues: new { area = "" }, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
    }
    if (User.IsInRole(Clinic.Enums.RolesEnum.Customer.ToString()))
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Customer", "Index", "Customer", routeValues: new { area = "" }, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
    }
}
```

When I log in as Salesman I see only one link which shoud be visible for Salesman but when I log in as Admin I see Admin and Customer link. I tried to debug stopping on User.IsInRole line but it doesn't go anywhere from there so I'm not sure which function is called to check roles assigned to user. Any help would be appreciated.

What is important, admin has only Admin role assigned in my database. I also see that using

```
if(UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(userId, "Admin").Result)
```

instead of

```
User.IsInRole("Admin")
```

works fine. So what's the problem with this function? What did I forgot to implement to make it works?

Comment: Are you sure user account you use to login as `Admin` is not `Customer` also in your Db?

Comment: There is no user with Customer role in my database. Only one admin with Admin role and several users with Salesman role.

Comment: I'm having this problem also, have implemented a custom user manager which provides custom user role logic, however calling User.IsInRole returns the default functionality. Did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the solution was to clear all cookies related to your site from browser